# Yii: a $_GET param to restrict output by CGridView?

Tags: yii

Are there any special `$_GET` parameters for `/admin` tables, which would restrict the table to only rows whose given field has a given value?

There are `?XXX_sort=` parameters which affect sorting. I expect that there should be similar parameters but for filtering instead sorting.

Or should I fetch a `$_GET` parameter and modify the `->criteria` myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filter critiera is by default created in the `search()` method of your model. If you want specific filtering by `$_GET` parameter, you should add some code to your controller, where you inspect the content of `$_GET` and set the filter attributes accordingly on your model.

Blatant self promotion: Maybe you can also get some inspiration from my [xcrudcontroller](https://github.com/mikehaertl/xcrudcontroller) extension. It explains a filter pattern that I use regularly and also how to get nice looking URL parameters for your filtering (have a look at the bottom of the README).